# recursive relation for putting signs in 2*n table

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

Consider we have a $2\times n$ table and we want to put a sign in some of the cells, and we don't put signs in both adjacent cells
give a recursive phrase that shows that how many ways we can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Let $A(n)$ be the number of $2 \times n$ boards filled as you say with the bottom row empty, $B(n)$ with a sign on the left, $C(n)$ with a sign on the right.  You can pu an empty row below anything, so $A(n)=A(n-1)+B(n-1)+C(n-1)$ Write the other two recurrences.  Note that $B(n)=C(n)$ and you should be able to find a recurrence just for $A(n)$

Comment: I didn't understand what you said. please explain more about $A(n) , B(n) ,C(n)$

Comment: I am envisioning the board as two columns.  The recurrence relations tell you how many ways there are to to fill a board with $n$ rows, given what is on the bottom row after $n-1$.  If the next to bottom row is empty, you can put any new bottom row on.  If there is a sign on the left in the next to bottom, you can leave the bottom blank, or you can put one on the right.